# A lemma about the Galois group of radical extensions in Rotman's book Advanced Modern Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, finite-fields, extension-field

Here is the proof of **Lemma A-5.19** in Chapter A-5 of Rotman's book *Advanced Modern Algebra*. (What he calls a 'pure extension' is commonly called 'radical extension' by most authors.)

[image]

I am confused by the case where $\mathrm{Characteristic}\,k = p_{1}$, as underlined in the screenshot above. It is based on a former example, which is as following:

[image]

In **Example A-5.8**, the base field $k$ is assumed to be in the form $\mathbb{F}_{p}(t)$ where $\mathbb{F}_{p}$ is a finite field of order $p$. But in **Lemma A-5.19** this assumption is dropped, and the base field is only assumed to be $\mathrm{Characteristic}\,k$. Can anyone help me understand why the assumption can be dropped while using **Example A-5.8** to prove **Lemma A-5.19**?

Comment: Hint: note that $K_1/k$ is a radical extension of prime type $p_1$, if char$k=p_1$, then the case follows from the example.

Comment: @S.R.Albert Thanks. But in the example $k$ is assumed to be a finite field, while in the lemma the assumption is dropped off.

Comment: The equation $x^p-t=(x-\alpha)^p$ still holds whenever char $k=p$.

Comment: @S.R.Albert Thanks. I now understand. It seems that the author sometimes refers to a former proposition so as to imply that the method used to prove the former proposition can be purely duplicated or slightly modified to serve as part of the proof to the current proposition, rather than to give a straightforward application of the argument. I didn't recognize this as one of these circumstances.